# Cannot read properties of undefined ('reading params')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can anyone help me on resolving my error
**Here is my code:**

```
const ProductScreen = ({match, history}) => {
    const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.getProductDetails);
    const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (product && match.params.id !== product._id){
            dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
        }
    }, [dispatch, product, match]);
```

**The error occurs on the if statement**. Thank you in advance for helping!

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krnjc.png)

Comment: What’s unclear about the error message? What debugging have you done?

Comment: you can check the passed `match` value

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `undefined` (or not passing anything) for the `match` variable. Check the code referencing it this component and be sure that it always passes a prop with name `match` in.